# Persistence annotations in Spring MVC 3

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, persistence

I'm investigating the pros and cons of switching from Struts 2 to Spring MVC 3.  I've gone the route of building test projects using annotation based controllers, but I'm struggling with how to set up my connection to my repository object.  In XML it'd be this:

```
<bean name="/viewfood.htm"
    class="hellospringmvc.controller.ViewFoodController"
    p:foodRepository-ref="foodRepository"
    p:viewName="viewfood" />
```

with the reference to the repository in the properties.  How do I translate this into an annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the bean above you are referencing the foodRepository bean from the controller . To manage this with annotation ,

1. Use component scan to autodetect the @Repository , @Service annotation - It dosen't matter much if you use either of them but @Repository makes sense .
2. Mark your DAO class object with @Repository . See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch04s12.html) for the reference
3. The beans are then autodetected and you will have a bean with the first letter of class name lower cased . or you can specify your own bean name using @Repository("foodRepository")